# referencing a nested tab in rmarkdown/js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs, r-markdown

I'm not too familiar with JavaScript or CSS but I use bits and pieces of it in RMarkdown. I'm working on a document that has a page with tiles/buttons that are used as navigation buttons to get to other tabs in my RMarkdown (crediting Allen O'Brien for this code!). These all work great but I am wondering how to create a tile that navigates to a specific sub-tab. So for instance I have these three buttons:

```
{js, echo = FALSE}

// Set destination for clicks on the id tabs after page is ready
$(document).ready ( function () {

// When tile 1 (#tile1) is clicked, navigate to the report-details tab.
$( "#tile1" ).on( "click", function() {
$('.nav-pills li a[href="#individuals"]').tab('show');
});

// When tile 2 (#tile2) is clicked, navigate to the report-details tab.
$( "#tile2" ).on( "click", function() {
$('.nav-pills li a[href="#hormone-plots"]').tab('show');
});

// When tile 3 (#tile3) is clicked, navigate to the report-details tab.
$( "#tile3" ).on( "click", function() {
$('.nav-pills li a[href="#species-comparison"]').tab('show');
});


});
```

Each of these tabs have additional tabs on that page that I've created just as a new tabset like this:

```
## Individuals {- .tabset}

### #4 {- .tabset}
```

And what I'd like to do is have a button that references let's say Individual #4, instead of having to click the Individuals button, then clicking on the Individual #4 subtab on that page. Any suggestions?

Here is a clearer update- this is how my current markdown doc is set up. The highlights is the page with all the buttons. All buttons right now are referencing headers with two ## (like Individual Whales), but I'm trying to build buttons that can also reference the ### headers (like Blue Whale 617698)

```
# {- .tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## Highlights {-}

<div>
  <div class="info-tile" id="tile1" style = "background: salmon;">
   <span class = "info-tile-large-text">Individual Profiles</span> <br />
  </div>
  
</div>

## Individual Whales {- .tabset}

### Blue Whale 617698 {- .tabset}
```

Comment: What is `#tile1` in your file? Are the tile# tabsets? Are they headings in your RMD file? An element id attribute in the HTML?

Comment: @Kat I added a clearer update for you that will hopefully help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whew! This didn't look like it would be all that hard, but wow! I found a lot of methods that broke the tab set!

Here is a method that works regardless of how many or how deeply you nest your tab sets.

I ended up using JS instead of JQuery. I used a nest within a nest within a nest, so I could make sure it was still going to work. If this is over the top, let me know, and I'll make a simpler version.

[image] [image]

The image on the right shows that the 3rd level-1 tabset's first level-2 tabset is where the 'Individuals' > 4 is.

You can see your button below the heading 'Analysis.' The button can be moved anywhere (that I could think to test) and it will still work.

The styling is just for the button.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "4/9/2022"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<style>
.info-tile {
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #000000;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid salmon;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px; 
  padding: 6px 50px;
  text-decoration: none; /*no underline!!*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
.info-tile:active { /*simulate movement*/
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
</style>
````

The nested tab sets

````
# Analysis {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

<a class="info-tile" id="tile1" style="background: salmon; color:black; font-face: bold;">Individual Profiles</a>

## 1

### 1 A {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

#### 1.1 

```{r p11, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 1, y = 2)
```

#### 1.2

```{r p12, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 1, y = 2)
```

## 2

### 2 A  {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

#### 2.1

```{r p21, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 1, y = 2)
```

#### 2.2

```{r p22, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 1, y = 2)
```

## 3 

### Individuals {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

#### 4                   <!--- BUTTON TARGET IS HERE!!!---->

```{r p1, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 1, y = 2)
```
    
#### 3.2 

```{r p2, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 4, y = 10)
```

----

### 3 B {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

#### 3.3

```{r p3, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 1, y = 10)
```

#### 3.4

```{r p4, echo=FALSE}
plot(x = 1:100, y = 100:1)
```
````

Last but not least, the JS to make the button do it's thing

````
```{r mine,results="asis",engine="js"}
// send me where I realllllly want to go
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector('a#tile1').addEventListener('click', doIt);
  function doIt(){
    document.querySelector('a[href*="#section-6"]').click(); //section 3
    document.querySelector('a[href*="#section-7"]').click(); // Indiv 4
  }
}, 100); // a tiny delay... just in case I'm running behind

```
````

Comment: THANK YOU! Your help is greatly appreciated. In the JS code, how are the sections numbered? For instance - how do I know which is section 6 or 7? This will be helpful when adding more buttons later on.

Comment: Of course! (Sheesh, I should have explained that!) You can literally count the tab sets. So `## 1` is `section` (like section 0); `### 1.1` is `section-1`, `### 1.2` is `section-2`, `##2` is `section-3`, and so on. In the code, you 'click' on the parent tab, then the child tab.  If you just tried `section-7` for example or `section-8`, the screen won't change. Behind the scenes the tab is active, but the page or tab they're on (3 or `section-6`) isn't 'on'. Let me know if this isn't clear-I'll add more details to my answer.