# How to create a working reference to specific tabset in Rmarkdown and not for all subsets?

Tags: html, r, tabs

As example, I have the following document with 2 tabs. I want to provide a link in the text to each tab:

````
---
title: Use tabs to organize content
output: html_document
---

To get access faster click on [tables](#tab) and [plots](#plt)

You can turn parallel sections to tabs in `html_document` output.

## Results {.tabset}

### Plots {#plt}

We show a scatter plot in this section.

```{r, fig.dim=c(5, 3)}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .5, .1))
plot(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, pch = 19)
```

### Tables {#tab}

We show the data in this tab.

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

However, only `[plots](#plt)` link work since the tab is active, while `[tables](#tab)` will only work if i switch tab.

Is it possible to make both links work?

Comment: Unfortunately, not possible https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/718

Comment: Look here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845769/referencing-a-nested-tab-in-rmarkdown-js> this might be helpful.